# implementing a scroll to top function with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have been following this tutorial http://brocknunn.com/untame/scroller/ I have notices that when its in tablet/mobile view the nav bar vanishes .if I wanted to use the non static nav for desktop how would I implemented a return to top button Or make my nav static on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the body top position and scrollTop, using jQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var bodyPos = $("body").position().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: bodyPos+"px" });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kQqm8/